# Accumulate data from two forms asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to collect data from users. I have to collect some data like: Name, email in the first step, then when he click continue, he will provide another data about his work experience and then hit submit. I will send the data to the server when he click the submit button.

I am planning two use two partial views for each of the forms (frmPersonalInfo, formwork). When he click "Continue" after providing the his personal information I will hide the "frmPersonalInfo" and show the other one.

My question is that how can I accumulate the data from both forms so I can send that to server. Can hidden fields serve the goal since I am having two forms and how?

Comment: Just have one form

Comment: Have a single `<form>` element. Put your two partial views in it. Have the second partial view (inside a div) hidden at the start. When they click continue show the second div and hide the div surrounding the first partial. _Also show the submit button at this point._ If the `<form>` element surrounds both partials then both sets of data will be submitted to the server together when submit is clicked.

Comment: The values will be posted to the server if the fields are hidden right? I am just suspicious about that part, that's why I was asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of data persistence choices in mvc like TempData or Session State.

for ex.

```
TempData[“tempContent”] = “Name”;
```